# Connect two wordpress containers with same NGINX docker

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-compose

I use nginx in a docker to connect my two wordpress websites, which are dockerized too.

I can set up one website with the following settings:

In docker-compose.yml

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./web_ndnb_prod/src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
    depends_on:
      - web_ndnb_test
      - web_ndnb_prod
```

In my NGINX conf file located in /nginx/conf.d

```
server {
        [...]
        root /var/www/html/;
        [...]
}
```

However to add a 2nd website, I try to change the root and the websites return a 404

In docker-compose.yml

```
nginx:
    image: nginx:alpine
    volumes:
      - ./web_ndnb_prod/src:/var/www/web_ndnb_prod
      - ./web_ndnb_test/src:/var/www/web_ndnb_test
      - ./nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
    depends_on:
      - web_ndnb_test
      - web_ndnb_prod
```

In one of the 2 NGINX conf files

```
server {
        [...]
        root /var/www/web_ndnb_prod/;
        [...]
}
```

If I execute

```
sudo docker exec -ti nginx ls /var/www/web_ndnb_prod
```

It outputs the wordpress files correctly

Why does Nginx not find them?

---

Edit 1

The main nginx.conf file is

```
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

Comment: I would expect your nginx container to forward requests to the wordpress containers. Having nginx serve the files directly seems wrong to me.

Comment: probably to do with the main nginx.conf file directives, check if you need to also mount it specifically instead of the entire `/etc/nginx` folder and fix the file locations there

Comment: Just edited the post to include nginx.conf.
It does not contain info about the root path

Comment: what are the permissions for the files in the mounted filesystem? add the output for `ls -la ./web_ndnb_prod/src` on your host machine